# Can I have a numeric x-axis with an Excel stacked area plot?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have some data that I can scatter plot like this:
[image: Scatter plot]

However, I want to make a stacked line plot (area plot) like this:
[image: Stacked area plot]

But when I change the chart type to a stacked area plot, then the x-axis becomes a series and not a numeric axis. Is there a way to have a stacked area plot with a numeric x-axis like the scatter plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the labels to look like in the first plot: you can modify the labels in Axis Options\ Labels for how many you get and Axis Options\Number for the format.

However, when plotting a stacked area, by default Excel does not use the values of your x-series. It just uses them as text labels. (Unlike a scatter plot).

I think that by '*numeric*' you want the points to use the x-values as values and not just text labels.

For this, there is a weird workaround, by using dates to use the x-coordinate of your data:

1. Select the x-axis, right click and `Format Axis`
2. `Axis Options` \ `Axis Type`: set to '`Date Axis`' to trick excel into thinking your x coordinates are dates.
3. In the `Units`, set `major` to 1000 Days, `minor` to 1 Days, and Base to Day
4. `Axis Options` \ `Number` : set `Category` to `Number`, `Decimal places` to 0, and no 1000 separator.

you might need to play around a bit to get exactly what you want.

Comment: The date hack worked perfectly when I set the major unit to 100 days. Thanks for this obscure, but effective tip!

Comment: There's a detailed guide to this hack here: https://peltiertech.com/fill-under-between-series-in-excel-chart/